# python watchdog stops capturing events after a few mins

Tags: python, watchdog

I'm running a python script to monitor and log any file changes in a specific folder using watchdog. The script runs for about 12 hours but after around 15 mins of running and logging the file changes, the script stops capturing any events even though there are new files being dropped in the folder.

I did check and the python script is still running in the background.

Can anyone advise why?

```
import os
import logging
import time
import datetime
from watchdog.observers import Observer 
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

#Functions for event handler
def on_created(event):
    
    #Checking file size
    file_size = -1
    while file_size != os.path.getsize(event.src_path):
        file_size = os.path.getsize(event.src_path)
        time.sleep(5)
    logging.info("File_created=" + event.src_path + "; file_size=" + str(file_size))
    
def on_modified(event):
    logging.info("File_modified=" + event.src_path + "; file_size=" + str(file_size))

def on_deleted(event):
    logging.info("File_deleted=" + event.src_path)

def on_moved(event):
    logging.info("File_moved=" + event.src_path)

def file_checker():

    logdate = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename='file_monitor_'+logdate+'.log', format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s : %(message)s',datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    
    
    #Set folder to monitor
    path = '/data/files/current'
    
    # Initialize Filesystem event handler     
    event_handler = FileSystemEventHandler()
    
    # Call the event handler functions
    event_handler.on_created = on_created
    #event_handler.on_modified = on_modified
    event_handler.on_deleted = on_deleted
    event_handler.on_moved = on_moved
    
    # Initialize Observer 
    observer = Observer() 
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=False) 
  
    # Start the observer 
    observer.start() 
    try:
        logging.info("Monitoring started")
        while True: 
            # Set the thread sleep time 
            time.sleep(2) 
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
        logging.info("Monitoring stopped")
    observer.join() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_checker()
```

Comment: Is `filename=file_monitor_'+logdate+'.log'` really missing a `'` in your source code? It should look like `filename='file_monitor_'+logdate+'.log'` surely.

Comment: Correct - the source code has the `'`. I deleted the first part of the filename for privacy reason

Comment: How large does your log file get as your program runs? How big is it by the time the program stops?

Comment: <2 KB. The log file only contains at most 20 lines before it stops registering the events